# Transform values in a list of dictionaries using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of dictionaries, like so:

```
matrices = [
    { "name": 'dark_matter_and_gas', 'matrix': dark_matter_a_matrix},
    { "name": 'dark_matter_and_gas', 'matrix': dark_matter_b_matrix},
    { "name": 'dark_matter_and_gas', 'matrix': dark_matter_c_matrix},
    { "name": 'dark_matter_and_gas', 'matrix': dark_matter_d_matrix},
    { "name": 'dark_matter_and_gas', 'matrix': dark_matter_e_matrix},
]
```

Where each `'matrix'` value is a pandas matrix object, and `dark_matter_a_matrix.dtypes`, for instance, returns a series of floats, for each matrix.

---

Now I'd like to do some transformation to all matrices in the dictionary, in one line.

The transformation would apply some `function(matrix)` to all dict values at once.

In pandas I would use `apply()` with `lambda` in a DataFrame, like so:

```
new_matrices = matrices['matrix'].apply(lambda x: function(x))
```

---

Which is the best way to this to the dictionary? I must keep the dictionary with the same structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the dictionaries in `matrices` and apply `function` to each of the DataFrames in each dictionary:

```
for d in matrices:
    d['matrix'] = d['matrix'].apply(lambda x: function(x))
```

I guess you could write it as a list comprehension as well:

```
matrices = [{'name': 'dark_matter_and_gas', 'matrix': d['matrix'].apply(lambda x: function(x))} for d in matrices]
```

but it's a lot less efficient in this case since you can modify each dictionary in loop without creating a new list.